# Downloading corrupt PDF file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

I am developing a feature in ASP.NET to download pdf file from `byte[]`.

So, we are using `Winnovative.PdfConverter.GetPdfBytesFromHtmlString` feature to get the pdf bytes. In below code, the `data` variable is a `byte[]` returned by
`Winnovative.PdfConverter.GetPdfBytesFromHtmlString`.

Therefore, the `data` variable alrady has the bytes that needs to be written in the pdf file.

NOTE: When I do `File.WriteAllBytes("a path", data)` a pdf file is created and can be read and is not corrupt.

The reason I want to use `HttpResponse` is because I want the file to be downloaded because that is what the client wants.

In Short, I want the code written below to take the `byte[] data` variable, write it to a pdf file and download it.

Following is the code:

```
HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.Clear();
response.ClearContent();
response.ClearHeaders();
response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
response.CacheControl = "private";
response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"; size=" + (object)data.Length);
response.AddHeader("Content-Length", data.Length.ToString((IFormatProvider)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
response.Flush();
response.BinaryWrite(data);
response.Flush();
response.End();
```

When I run the Web app the download occurs smooth but the file fails to load when opened.

Comment: That should be `application/octet-stream`

Comment: @SLaks thank you for the reply, but the file downloaded are still corrupt. Although, now I can see error message: `Errors:

Open file.
0x80410108 - E - The end-of-file marker was not found.
0x8041010A - E - The 'startxref' keyword or the xref position was not found.
Recover XREF table.
0x80410306 - E - The "Length" key of the stream object is wrong.
    - Object No.: 20
0x80410307 - E - The "endstream" keyword is missing.
    - Object No.: 20`

Comment: What is the size of the downloaded file? Zero?

Comment: @OguzOzgul there is no file, the vaiable `byte[] data` has length of `236` which I got from `data.Length.ToString()`

Comment: Look at the data in the data object, then look at what's in the PDF file. You may have both of them matching in which case the problem is what's put into data in your app. Also, may be a problem to call Flush() the first time.

Comment: @DavidThielen Thanks for the reply. I did checked the data object, it looks fine because `File.WriteAllBytes("a path", data)` creates a readable pdf file. Although, the downloaded corrupt pdf file has characters like `%PDF-1.4\u000d\u000a%����\u000d\u000a1 0 obj` and the readable file has `%PDF-1.4 %´µ¶·1 0 obj`

Comment: Those are not identical files according to what you listed. I think that's a problem.

Answer (score -3):

Updating this answer in 2020 as this is how I do it today in an ASP.NET WebAPI controller. This is a full ApiController example:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using MediatR;
using NLog;
using Company.Core.Enums;
using Company.Portal.DependencyResolution;
using Company.Portal.Helpers;
using Company.Services.CustomerResource;

namespace Company.Portal.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [RoutePrefix("api/Commerce")]
    public class CommerceController : ApiController
    {
        private static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        private readonly IMediator _mediator = IoC.Container.GetInstance<IMediator>();

        [Route("Order/pdf/{orderNumber}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> OrderPdf(int orderNumber, string emailAddress)
        {
            var userSecurityContext = User.Identity.GetUserSecurityContext();
            Logger.Debug($"{Request.Method}|{Request.RequestUri}|{userSecurityContext}");
            HttpResponseMessage response;

            if (userSecurityContext.OrderOrigin.IsCompanyOrderOrigin())
            {
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, $"{userSecurityContext.OrderOrigin} not authorized");
            }
            else
            {
                var request = new GetCustomerOrderPdfRequest(orderNumber, emailAddress, userSecurityContext.OrderOrigin);
                byte[] pdfContent = await _mediator.Send(request);
                if (pdfContent == null)
                {
                    response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, $"Unable to find resource. Resource {orderNumber} may not exist.");
                }
                else
                {
                    response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                    response.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(pdfContent));
                    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
                    response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = pdfContent.Length;
                    if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse($"inline; filename={userSecurityContext.OrderOrigin}-Order-{orderNumber}.pdf", out var contentDisposition))
                    {
                        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
                    }
                }
            }
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know there's a controller? Why are you assuming this is MVC and not Web Forms?

Comment: @mason OP did not specify and based on market share it is safer to assume MVC than Webforms - https://developer.telerik.com/topics/net/asp-net-intersections-developers-share-2017-platform-choice/

Comment: We do not base our answers on "what is the currently popular technology" but rather "What technology is being asked about". If you are unsure, you should leave a comment asking for clarification rather than providing an answer that may not be relevant.  And that survey and its conclusions look absolutely silly.

Comment: Thank You for replying. I did made change to my question above to make it a little clearer. Hope it helps. Thanks.

Comment: @austin You still haven't tagged your question to appropriately state what framework you're using. Web Forms or MVC etc.

Comment: @tawman The question has been tagged as Web API and you'll now need to adjust your answer appropriately.

Comment: @mason this is a WebApi controller example

Comment: The link you provided in your answer leads to an ASP.NET MVC class. While MVC is similar to Web API, they are not the same and you'll want to adjust your answer accordingly. That's why it's important to wait until the question is clear before answering.

Comment: @mason updated answer with a year 2020 working example